# jquery SerialScroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, serialscroll

I'm trying to implement jquery serialScroll on one of my carousels with prev/ next buttons however i'm only able to get it to work when I pass in unique id's for prev and next. what I would like to do is pass in a selector.

So with markup like this:

```
<div id="screen">
..
<img class="prev" ..>
..
<img class="next" ..>
..
</div>
```

This seems to work:

```
$(#screen).serialScroll({
  //..
  prev: 'img.prev',
  next: 'img.next'
});
```

But this does not:

```
$(#screen).serialScroll({
  //..
  prev: '#screen .prev',
  next: '#screen .next'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting prev and next on a tag (prev and next). Change to `#screen .prev` and `#screen .next` (notice the dot) and it should work.

Comment: Sorry - that was a typo in my question...i am using #screen .prev and #screen .next (just updated that)

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never - the plugin selects items within the context of the selector.

```
function getItems(){
    return $( items, pane );
};
```

So with your latter snippet, it actually evaluates to `#screen #screen .prev`, hence why none are found ;)